# Why doesn't the timeline speed match reality?

Tags: animation, timeline

My timeline seconds/frames are not showing the same amount of time passing in as reality when I hit play.

After 8 seconds of real time have passed I'm only on second 2, frame 30, of Blender. And changing my frame rate between 60 and 24 doesn't update the number of frames per second on the timeline as I expect it would, coming from an animator like Synfig Studio.

How do I make the seconds/frames of Blender match reality please?

[image]

---

If this is not a simple newb question then my project file is available here if anyone is willing to look:  https://we.tl/t-aq9ZzayleM

Comment: Playback speed is highly dependent on computer performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the timeline is set to "*No Sync*" (to the right of the playback buttons) Blender will try to display every single frame, even if doing so can take more than 1/24th of a second, therefore it will lag behind. This happens if the scene is too complicated (too many vertices, complex modifiers, rendered view being enabled, etc) for the hardware to handle quickly.

Changing to "*Frame Dropping*" will tell Blender to skip as many frames as it's needed to catch up with the real time. It will be synced, but be aware that it could be skipping a substantial amount of frames.

---

Comment: Thanks!  And is there any way to make Blender use time, not frames, as the basis for animation so everything doesn't break when I change frame rate? (Like how you can set a music project in a DAW's timebase from beats and bars to minutes and seconds)

Comment: I don't think that's possible natively, but don't take my word for it. If a search on the site doesn't yield meaningful results, you can try asking another question